# Storing data for faster search

Tags: mysql, mongodb, data-structures, database

Just a general question.

I was wondering how companies like facebook and google search through millions of data in such a short span of time.

Lets say if i have to login, I enter my user credentials on the login page. How does fb and google store username and password so that they can go through millions/ billions of username and check if the user exist or not?

If there is a startup, how should they save their user's data so that later on searching and extracting users details can be faster. Should we create a separate table for user based on first alphabet of their user name? or is their any other better way to do this?

Let me know if there is any good article related to this question that you would suggest me to read.

Comment: This question is too broad and off-topic (asking for off-site resources). One hint I can give you: don't assume your startup's application is going to be the next Google or Facebook and you'll be fine. Scale when needed.

Comment: @codeCaster : I am not assuming that my startup would be as huge as fb or google. I used those companies as example. Just wanted to take precaution so that scaling would be easier when required.
Thanks for your feedback

Comment: There is no silver bullet, no "one size fits all" answer. Scale when needed. Don't over-engineer, don't optimize prematurely. Identify bottlenecks when or they appear (however minor), don't think you can predict all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for data in a centralized database will be a bottle neck as the application data size grows. If you are thinking of scaling problems when starting the development of application itself, make sure your system can easily be deployed to parallel systems.

For example, think of scenarios where your data can't fit on a single database server however good configuration it is. You must split this data on to multiple hosts. This is called sharding. In sharding, data gets distributed to multiple hosts based on some keys. Take the same example of Facebook. It can maintain a database server for each country (just an assumption, I don't really know how they have implemented it). So when a user tries to login from India, his user will be searched only in Indian users database rather than the whole user base of Facebook. Considering the huge database size of Facebook, reducing the search space from whole user base to indian user base will definitely improve the query performance.

Database servers like MongoDB, and ElasticSearch provide in built support for sharding. With the help of these features, we can horizontally scale a system by adding more and more machines than vertical scaling (Scaling a single server to it's fullest capacity).